# How to create excellent characters animation in Cocos2D?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

This is my implementation to create an animation to an enemy that is inserted in the scene.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];    
CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animation];
[animation addSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"enemy_1.png"]];
[animation addSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"enemy_2.png"]];
animation.delayPerUnit = 0.1;
[_enemy runAction:
 [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
  [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
```

This is just one example of how to realize an animation.
For example, if I have a "Boss" made ​​up of several parts, I would like to make it very quaint with animations in different parts of the body.

Is there a way to create animations smoother than the continuous replacement of images?

Computationally, this is the best you can do, or are there more efficient techniques?

Thanks for the help

Comment: only 2 frames? Use more frames to make animation smooth, also adjust  delayPerUnit :P

Comment: Of course, adding images, I get a much more fluid animation :) My question was about the techniques with which you can make animations. For example, if I have a "Boss" made ​​up of several parts, I would like to make it very quaint with animations in different parts of the body.

Comment: If you have a couple extra bucks, you should look into sprite & level helper. You can assign one sprite with a series of images to make a very smooth animation, then you just access that sprite via code and it automatically does the animation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Loading multiple images, one after another is the only way to 'animate' within cocos2d. Of course for various effects that can be mathematically defined you can use functions that are provided within the framework (like rotating, resizing, moving or physics based animation such as falling or bouncing)

If your artists provide a clean spritesheet with fluid frame by frame animation you'd be surprised by how smooth your animation can look.

Answer (score 1):

```
//if you are using spritesheet then use this...for loading or sprites in your game...

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"walkcycle.plist"] ;
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"walkcycle.png"];
[heroWorldLayer addChild:spriteSheet];

NSMutableArray *enemyFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= 11; ++i) {
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Run_Anim00%02d.png", i]];
    [enemyFrames addObject:frame];
}
id enemyAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:enemyFrames delay:1.0/22.0];
id enemyAnimate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:enemyAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

 id _runAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:enemyAnimate];
[_enemy runAction:_runAction];
```